# Untar a file stored on a base64 encoded string in chunks

Tags: php, base64, tar, output-buffering

I need to untar a file that is stored on a PHP script in base64 format. I'm able to untar it with something like:

```
function decompress($buffer) {
    $fp = popen("base64 -d | tar -xJf -", "w");
    fwrite($fp, $buffer);
    pclose($fp);
}

/*...*/
$fs_res = ob_start("decompress");
?>VERY___LONG___BASE64___STRING<?php
ob_end_flush();
```

...and it seems working fine because the package is uncompressed.

The problem is that the whole base64 string is passed to the callback all at once, but I fear it could saturate the RAM if the tar file is bigger, but I can't figure a way to divide the buffer in chunks.

Comment: Why are you doing this over just using a string?

Comment: It's a backup system in a single file

Comment: Let me expand a bit: a first php script generates a second php script that contains this tar file converted in a string via base64 utility. This second script converts back the string in binary and passes it to tar via pipe